# Did I commit shirk or not? Urgent

Tags: halal-haram, allah, shirk

My masjid has tafsir everyday after asr prayer and after the tafsir session the imam makes dua and I felt like he would scold me ( the imam ) if I don't raise my hands so I raised my hands and then I thought this could be shirk so I immediately stopped Is this shirk can someone plese help.

Comment: Why should it be shirk? Elaborate! (See [ask]).

Comment: Is it shirk by the way of doing it for the sake of other than Allah @Medi1Saif I was gonna say Aameen to the dua I just raised the hands due to the fear

Comment: This still doesn't make much sense why do you do du'a for the sake of others? When a person makes du'a it is sunnah to raise ones hands.